# Express JS: how to know if request is for static asset?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am writing middleware for some specific task, which should **not** be executed when request is for static assets (from client folder: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")));)

So how can i know that particular request is for static asset or is being served from "client" folder?

I have below code

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")));   
app.use(someCustomMiddleware());
```

i am seeing that requests for static assets like for css/js files is still going thru someCustomMiddleware(). My requirement is that someCustomMiddleware() should not process request for static assets.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it before your other routes. If a request is made for a static item then it will go to `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")));` first, and then your routes.

Ex. Let's say your public folder has some `css` folder with a file `style.css` in it. Let's say your routes look like this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
app.use(someMiddleware);
```

If you access `/css/style.css`, it will hit `express.static` and serve the file, and will not go to that `'/'` route.

Comment: I have below code
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")));
app.use(someCustomMiddleware());

i am seeing that request for static assets like for css/js files is still going thru someCustomMiddleware()

Comment: Thanks @patosai but this does not seem to be working for me. i have edited ticket with some more code, if you can help.

Comment: I just tried this and it works for me. Are you sure your static directory is correct?

Comment: @Patosai +1 I recommend you elaborate your answer and furnish with more code - you've shown a negative case. Show a [positive case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23642971/145682)